# MFC CRecordset heap corruption detected at Close()

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, oracle11g, windows-7-x64, recordset

I recently upgraded my operating system from Windows XP to Windows 7 SP1 64 bit. We are using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition and Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

When I try to execute this code I am getting the below exceptions

try
    {
        CDatabase *pDatabase = CDatabaseConnection::getDatabaseConnectionProcessLog();

```
    ORSProcessLog rsProcessLog(pDatabase);
    CString strFilter = _T("SELECT PROCESS_ID, MESSAGE FROM OP_PROCESS_LOG");
    rsProcessLog.SetRowsetSize(1);
    if( !rsProcessLog.Open(CRecordset::dynaset, strFilter, CRecordset::appendOnly) )        
        return;

    if( !rsProcessLog.CanAppend() )
        return; 

    rsProcessLog.AddNew();          

    rsProcessLog.m_PROCESS_ID = gcsProcessID;
    rsProcessLog.m_MESSAGE = csMessageA;

    rsProcessLog.Update();
    rsProcessLog.Close();
}
catch ( CDBException* pEx )
{
    bException = true;
    pEx->GetErrorMessage(szCause, 255);
} 
catch( CException* pEx )
{
    bException = true;
    pEx->GetErrorMessage(szCause, 255);
}
```

where rsProcessLog is the CRecordset object using a successfully connected database pointer pDatabase

**In 32- bit Debug version I get a message box at rsProcessLog.Close(); with the below text**
Debug Error

Program: ......\Test.exe

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#506) at 0x0087F628. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Memory allocated at f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(2626)

(Please Retry to debug the application)

**In 32- bit Release version I get a message box at rsProcessLog.Close(); with the below text**
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Test.exe

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Test.exe or any of the DLLS it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Test.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

**The above code was a working code in Windows XP with the rest of the env remaining the same and it continues to run in Windows XP but not in Windows 7. Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Are you sure there nothing in your ORSProcessLog::Close()? Also, check the destructor of ORSProcessLog. It may have some unexpected code in it

Comment: What is executed at dbcore.cpp(2626). Knowing this might help you to find out who overwrites this section of memory. Also you are able to set a memory break point.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis of MFC `CRecordest` class I noticed that the problem appears after call to `::SqlSetPos` where `m_rgRowStatus` array allocated on the heap become damaged (one byte more is written on the heap).

First and clean approach to problem is to force `CRecordset` class to use update/delete SQL statements instead  of `::SqlSetPos` function. To achive this you need to open your database using `OpenEx` method with `CDatabase::userCursorLib` option.

```
CDatabase db;
db.OpenEx(ConnectionString, CDatabase:useCursorLib);
```

This will change some CRecordset functionalities. See more at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c689y99f.aspx

Second approach (dirty) is to reallocate `m_rgRowStatus` field, to use more memory on the heap, so call to `::SqlSetPos` will not write to unallocated memory.

One way to do that is to override `CRecordset::PreBindFields` function:

```
void CMyDerivedRecordset::PreBindFields()
{
    if  ( ! (m_dwOptions & useMultiRowFetch) )
    {
        delete [] m_rgRowStatus;
        m_rgRowStatus = new WORD[2];
    }

    CRecordset::PreBindFields();
}
```

You can do that in all of your `CRecordset` derived classes, or you can make one new `CRecordset` derived class which will become base class for all of your existing `CRecordset`derived classes.